# Adding and updating CSS rules via Javascript by replacing style block?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a few styles that need to be calculated and updated on resize using JavaScript, but are best applied conditionally through CSS.

Currently my plan is to assign an ID to a style block and use jQuery to replace the contents of the block using the .html() method. This approach seems to work fine in Chrome/Fireworks/Safari (OSX), but I am wondering if anyone has any experience with this method in other browsers or can forsee any problems.

Comment: It should work on all browsers. But it's better if you can modify element style properties using jquery's .css method rather than modifying a style block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work on all other browsers.

but if you don't need to support old browsers then I recommend taking alook at these CSS properties:

the css calc() function, and css vw, vh, vmin, vmax units. 
using these can really make your life much easier. 
keep in mind some of them not supported on old browsers.